# PHP - Undefined Session

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm attempting to make a login system, which then redirects to the appropriate pages if the right details were entered or not.

```
session_start();

$result = mysqli_query($con, "my query");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("Location: home.php");
}
else
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

However, if I enter the right details I get: "`Undefined variable: _SESSION`".

I don't really know what's going wrong here.

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: `_SESSION`? The name of the session variable is `$_SESSION`. Was that a spelling mistake? This function returns TRUE if it was successful, so try making a variable receive the return value and the `var_dump()` it.

Comment: No the PHP error definitely misses the $. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you start session ( `session_start()`) at the top of every php file where you want to use the `$_SESSION` superglobal array.

Comment: His code is already showing a session_start() at the very top

Comment: @AlanChavez : At the top of this php file, not file where he is redirected(I guess).

Comment: Consider also checking if it is started, before that. `if(!session_id()) session_start();`, otherwise warning may appear, it was something like: *Session already started*.

Comment: Yep, it was a problem with the file it was being directed to, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the `session_start()` call is failing. The most common cause of this is you've started outputting to the browser already. This happens when you have whitespace or HTML before the opening `<?php` tag, or have any sort of `echo`/`print`/`printf`-type call before your call to `session_start()`.

One way to make sure that the session always gets started first is to use a file that is automatically prepended and have the entire contents of that file be `<?php session_start();`. To do this, you set the [`auto_prepend_file`](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) INI flag. This does have to be set before any PHP files are loaded, so you either need to use `.htaccess` or `php.ini` file.

Comment: Yep, it was a problem with the file it was being directed to, thanks.

Comment: So the question has been answered @user9993 ? If so, please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a drupal question? If so, this could help you: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107287/undefined-variable-session-in-template-php

Could you please show the rest of the code prior to `session_start()`? It's possible/likely that an error (in the previous code) or any output at all before the call to `session_start()` could be causing your error.